# To post an array of data pushed from UI using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, json

I made an array to push data through UI, what I want is to send the created array using angularjs post.

Here is my code:-

```
$scope.clinicWorkingSchedules = [ 
        {   workingDay: '',
            workingHours: []
        }
      ]

  $scope.sendClinicTiming= function(id,workingDay,fromTime,toTime){

   var data={
          'id':id,
          'clinicWorkingSchedules':clinicWorkingSchedules
         };
   $http.post($scope.API_url,
    data, config)
    .success(function(data, status));


  };
```

id is going correctly, but not able to send array.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.clinicWorkingSchedules = [ 
        {   workingDay: '',
            workingHours: []
        }
      ]

  $scope.sendClinicTiming= function(id,workingDay,fromTime,toTime){

   var data={
          'id':id,
          'clinicWorkingSchedules':$scope.clinicWorkingSchedules
         };
   $http.post($scope.API_url,
    data, config)
    .success(function(data, status));


  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.clinicWorkingSchedules =  
        {   workingDay: '',
            workingHours: {'fromTime':'', 'toTime':''}
        }


$scope.sendClinicTiming= function(id,workingDay,fromTime,toTime){

$scope.clinicWorkingSchedules.workingDay = workingDay;
$scope.clinicWorkingSchedules.workingHours.fromTime = fromTime;
$scope.clinicWorkingSchedules.workingHours.toTime= toTime;


   var data={
          'id':id,
          'clinicWorkingSchedules':$scope.clinicWorkingSchedules
         };
   $http.post($scope.API_url,
    data, config)
    .success(function(data, status));

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `$scope` before the array. The rest of your code is perfectly fine. Here is the code with changes.

```
var data={
    'id':id,
    'clinicWorkingSchedules': $scope.clinicWorkingSchedules
};
```